# Prolog - Chain rule for Step Siblings

Tags: prolog

I am a newbie to Prolog, and have a question regarding programming a "chain rule" for step-siblings that share a "common parent".

In my program, I am assuming that the existence of the **parent(X,Y)** fact that asserts that X is a parent of Y.

I need a rule **chain(X,Y,L):** if X is an *ancestor* of Y, then L is the *list* containing X, Y and all ancestors of Y who are also descendants of X, listed in descending order of age (*oldest first*). In other words, my list should contain *all* the people that *link a person with an ancestor*.

**Eg:** If **chain(peter,mary,[peter,paul,sue,mary])**, then **peter** is the parent of **paul**, **paul** is the parent of **sue**, and **sue** is the parent of **mary**.

**Note:** I am familiar with the **stepSibling(a,b)** relationship where their relationship is qualified via their parents **partner(X,Y)**; where siblings **a** and **b** are children of their *respective parents* via the relationship **child(a,X)** and **child(b,Y)**. *Hence*; I am only confused with the relationship where **both stepsiblings share a common parent**. **ie.** A child relationship that may look like this: **child(a,X)** and **child(b,X)**.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an interesting twist on the usual genealogy problems we discuss in early Prolog courses. Let's consider a simplification first, `ancestor(X,Y)` is true if X is an ancestor of Y.

So you have a predicate `parent(X,Y)` which says X is a parent of Y. You can write `ancestor/2` like this:

```
% base case: your parent is an ancestor
ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y).
ancestor(X, Z) :- parent(X, Y), ancestor(Y, Z).
```

With a sample database like this it should work fine:

```
parent(peter, paul).
parent(paul, sue).
parent(sue, mary).
```

This will work for a query like `ancestor(peter, mary)`, which is close to what you want. The next step would be to retain the chain, which would look something like this:

```
chain(X, Y, [X,Y])     :- parent(X, Y).
chain(X, Z, [X|Chain]) :- parent(X, Y), chain(Y, Z, Chain).
```

This appears to work:

```
?- chain(peter, mary, X).
X = [peter, paul, sue, mary] ;
false.
```

I worry though, because your question mentions step siblings and that the chain should include other people. Is that just chaff or do you have additional requirements? If so, they're not reflected in your example, so I may need you to augment your question with additional details.

Comment: The "other" element I was referring to was in regards to "all" other members who were also related along the same ancestor chain.

Your example above perfectly answers that for me.

Eg. 

?- chain(peter, mary, X)
X = [peter, paul, sue, mary];     // This is exactly what I was referring to.

I also successfully ran the program.

Thanks heaps!
:)